# PHP: Get PHP's variables, functions, constants from a php file

Tags: php, file, function, include, variables

Is there a way to get user-defined php functions, variables, constants from a php file?
Following functions are not the best way to do so because they get all decalred
functions/vars/constants (with hundreds of php's built-in constants and internal php functions):

```
get_defined_vars  
get_defined_functions  
get_defined_constants
```

Suppose i have this file **myfile.php**:

```
<?php
$title = 'Sample Application';
$copyright = 'Copyright &copy; 2009';
    $my_array = array('sarfraz', 'ahmed', 'chandio');

define ('_CASTE', 'chandio');
define ('_COUNTRY', 'Pakistan');


function add($val1, $val2)
{
    return ($val1 + $val2);
}

function subtract($val1, $val2)
{
    return ($val1 - $val2);
}
?>
```

Now how can i get all variables/functions/constants from that file and probably store in an array?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to try the PHP Tokenizer.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.tokenizer.php

From an external script:

```
<?php

var_dump(token_get_all(file_get_contents('myscript.php')));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

call `get_defined_functions`, then include the file, call `get_defined_functions` once again and compute the difference.

Answer (score 0):

To get all variables defined in a file

```
$init_var = get_defined_vars();
include_once('file_to_check.php');
$init_var2 = get_defined_vars();
unset($init_var2['init_var']);
$variables_defined_in_file = array_diff_key($init_var2, $init_var));
var_dump($variables_defined_in_file);
```

you should repeat above code by replacing get_defined_vars() for

```
get_defined_vars()  
get_defined_functions()  
get_defined_constants()
```